# How to make three pointer para short?

Tags: c, printf

The original question is the problem of my confusion, sorry.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func(int **p_in1, int **p_in2, int **p_in3){
  int *p_temp1 = (int *)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
  int *p_temp2 = (int *)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
  int *p_temp3 = (int *)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
       p_temp1[i] = i+1;
       p_temp2[i] = i+2;
       p_temp3[i] = i+3;
  }
  *p_in1 = p_temp1;
  *p_in2 = p_temp2;
  *p_in3 = p_temp3;
}

int main(){
    int *p_out1 = NULL, *p_out2 = NULL, *p_out3 =NULL;
    int i;
    func(&p_out1, &p_out2, &p_out3);

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%d", p_out1[i]);
        printf(" ");
        printf("%d", p_out2[i]);
        printf(" ");
        printf("%d\n", p_out3[i]);
    }

   free(p_out1);
   free(p_out2);
   free(p_out3);
   p_out1 = NULL;
   p_out2 = NULL;
   p_out3 = NULL;
   return 0;
}
```

I want to make the "func" much shorter by just use one para. How can I put the "p_in1, p_in2, p_in3" together in continuous memory space?

Comment: What output are you getting, and what were you expecting?

Comment: Works here: http://ideone.com/0uKo7. What does it print for you?

Comment: could you post the expected output and the received output?

Comment: Using malloc() for such a small buffer(s) is not something I would do.  Just put it on the stack.  With int p_temp1[5] then you won't have to free it.

Comment: To get your desired output, you will have to stop printing spaces after the digits, and you will need to loop through each array separately.  If you want all the output on one line, you will need to print a space after processing the first two arrays and a newline after the third.

Comment: I would have edited your title to make it clearer, but I can't quite figure out what you're trying to say.  Does "para" mean "paragraph"?  If so, what do you mean by "paragraph"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you've edited in the output that you wanted, the question can be answered.

Change your print loop to this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    printf("%d", p_out1[i]);
}
printf(" ");
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    printf("%d", p_out2[i]);
}
printf(" ");
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    printf("%d", p_out3[i]);
}
```

This will output:

```
12345 23456 34567
```

In your original code, you were interleaving the 3 arrays. What you wanted was to print each one separately.

EDIT: As for your second question, you can combine `p_out1`, `p_out2`, and `p_out1` into an array.

Here's your code with this done:

```
void func(int **p_in){
  int *p_temp1 = (int *)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
  int *p_temp2 = (int *)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
  int *p_temp3 = (int *)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
       p_temp1[i] = i+1;
       p_temp2[i] = i+2;
       p_temp3[i] = i+3;
  }
  p_in[0] = p_temp1;
  p_in[1] = p_temp2;
  p_in[2] = p_temp3;
}

int main(){
    int *p_out[3];
    func(p_out);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%d", p_out[0][i]);
    }
    printf(" ");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%d", p_out[1][i]);
    }
    printf(" ");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%d", p_out[2][i]);
    }

   free(p_out[0]);
   free(p_out[1]);
   free(p_out[2]);

   return 0;
}
```